# Request URL Too Long (20K characters) IIS 7

Tags: ios, iis-7

I have an iPad application which sends data to a .NET application. The iPad application was written by a bunch of monkeys who implemented all the requests as GET instead of POST.

The application is live now, and with the client's data is sending requests over 20k characters, which is giving me this response (using Safari, which has been tested to work with URLs of at least 80k characters):

[Generic 414 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRzBA.png)

Instead of the detailed IIS response I would get if, say, the request exceeded the requestFiltering/maxURL value in the web.config, which looks like this:

[IIS 414.14 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29U3m.png)

Since I am getting the generic error message instead of the IIS-specific message, it makes me think this is not due to something I can fix in configuration settings (I have maxURL set to 2 billion, just to be safe...)

I understand that the requests should be using POST, but I don't really have time to rewrite the iPad application at the moment, and all of my research has only turned up unhelpful responses which say "you **should** limit GET requests to 2K characters" "you **should** use a POST instead of a GET". If that is the only feedback you have, please don't bother answering. (For instance, I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) and it's answers.)

I need to know if I can throw in a quick workaround to make this function until I have time to do it the right way. And I'm also wondering if anyone knows about hard limitations URL lengths from either the iOS or IIS side, because I can't find any specifics.

Edit: My httpRuntime parameters are also set to accept far more than 20k characters.

Comment: what do you have for your `httpRuntime` parameters and what version of .NET?

Comment: Using .NET 4.0, and the httpRuntime parameters for maxUrlLength and maxQueryStringLength are also set to 2 billion.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old one, but in case someone will face it like I did yesterday - setting web.config parameters didn't help me either. What I've found was this MS article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129/en-us.
I've added two DWORD keys to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters**:

> MaxFieldLength = 65534 
>   MaxRequestBytes = 100000

**NOTE**: you need to restart your server or at least HTTP service to make these keys work.
 After restart I've managed to send a request with query string length up to ~32k characters (don't know why only ~32k though, maybe character encoding?). So I guess this is the limit for URL lenght in Windows 2003 and up.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue and this has solved it.

Comment: I used the same solution, but get the same limitation (32k). Did anyone overcame this limitation?

Answer (score -1):

If you are seeing this in multiple clients, it's likely to be your server settings. In the .NET 4.0's `httpRuntime` section, the maximum values for both [`maxUrlLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxurllength.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and [`maxQueryStringLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxQueryStringLength.aspx) are a 32 bit signed integer, or `2147483647`.

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="2147483647" maxQueryStringLength="2147483647" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I had my httpRuntime parameters set appropriately as well.

Comment: The maximum Value is : 2097151